# JAVA Display item from JList in JLabel

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, jlist, listselectionlistener

```
public class ListComboBox extends JFrame {

private String MIS = "MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION";
private String SIS = "SINGLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION";
private String SS = "SINGLE_SELECTION";
final int COUNTRIES = 9;
private String[] countries = {"Canada", "China", "Denmark",
    "France", "Germany", "India", "Norway", "United Kingdom",
    "United States of America"};
private JList<String> jlst = new JList<String>(countries);
private JLabel comboLabel = new JLabel("Choose Selection Mode: ");
private JComboBox jcbo = new JComboBox();
//to hold country labels
private JLabel countryLabel = new JLabel();

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ListComboBox frame = new ListComboBox();
    frame.setSize(400, 200);
    frame.setTitle("Exercise 17.14");
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // Center the frame
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public ListComboBox() {

    //Adding selection option to combobox
    jcbo.addItem(MIS);
    jcbo.addItem(SIS);
    jcbo.addItem(SS);

    // Register listener combobox
    jcbo.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
        @Override
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
            if (e.getItem() == MIS) {
                jlst.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
            }
            if (e.getItem() == SIS) {
                jlst.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
            }
            if (e.getItem() == SS) {
                jlst.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
            }
        }
    });

    //Combobox panel
    JPanel combopanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
    combopanel.add(comboLabel);
    combopanel.add(jcbo);
    add(combopanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    //List panel
    JScrollPane listpanel = new JScrollPane(jlst);
    add(listpanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    //Bottom label panel
    final JPanel labelpanel = new JPanel();
    labelpanel.add(countryLabel);
    add(labelpanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    //List listener
    jlst.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
        @Override
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(64);
            int[] indices = jlst.getSelectedIndices();
            int i;
            for (i = 0; i < indices.length; i++) {
                if (sb.length() > 0) {
                    sb.append(", ");
                }
                sb.append(countries[indices[i]]);
            }
            countryLabel.setText(sb.toString());
        }
    });
}
}
```

Good day, I need your help.

What I need code to do: Add selected country names from the list with scroll bar to the label below the list, remove them as they are unselected in the list.

List selection mode can be switched in JComboBox on top.
Everything works fine, but I cannot figure out the way for country names to properly appear inside the label.

Any tips on how I might accomplish that?

Thanks!

UPDATED!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setName` is used for internal identification of the component.  Imagin you've been give a list of components, all you know is you need to find the one with some unique identifier, that identifier is supplied via the `name` property.  It has no effect on the output of the component.

You need to use the `setText` method to change what is displayed on the screen.

The next problem you'll have is `setText` is a replacement method.  That is, it will replace what ever was previously applied with the new value.  What might need to do is build a temporary `String` of the values you want to display and then apply that value to the label, for example...

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(64);
for (i = 0; i < indices.length; i++) {
    if (sb.length() > 0) {
        sb.append(", ");
    }
    sb.append(countries[indices[i]]);
}        
countryLabel.setText(sb.toString());
```

Answer (score 2):

To set text on `JLabel` use `countryLabel.setText` instead of `countryLabel.setName`. Another issue is that in the posted code `countryLabel` is not added to the frame. I assume it should go into `labelpanel`, but this part is commented out.

Some other observations:

Do not mix light weight and heavy weight components. See [Mixing Heavyweight and Lightweight Components](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/mixing-components-433992.html). Instead of ScrollPane use `JScrollPane`, for example:

```
JScrollPane listpanel = new JScrollPane(jlst);
```

Also there is no need to `revalidate()` the container when you set text on `JLabel`. The label will be refreshed as a result of `setText()` method.

Comment: Thanks! I replaced setName() with setText(), ScrollPane with JScrollPane and revalidate() since it was no longer needed. However, I still have no idea how to make JLabel hold all selected countries in the list. I have tried: `countryLabel.setText(countryLabel.getText()+" "+countries[indices[i]]);` but obviously it didn't work.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad it helped you. You would have to build a single string from a list of items. Something like comma separated items. See @MadProgrammer answer that outlines a solution with `StringBuilder`.